# The probability of extinction

Tags: probability, random-variables, order-statistics

Consider the following modification of a branching process:

> A mature individual produces children according to the generating function $g(t)$. However, an individual becomes mature with probability $\alpha$ and dies before maturity with probability $1-\alpha$. We start with one immature individual.
>
> (a) Find the generating function of the number of individuals in the first two generations.
>   (b) Suppose that the offspring distribution
>       is geometric with parameter $p$. Determine the extinction
>       probability.

Is my working correct for both?

(a) The number of individuals in the first generation is $\alpha g(t)$ if the pioneer individual matures and 0 if it does not. The number of individuals in second generation would be $\alpha^2g(t)^2$.

(b) The number of individuals in the next generation is $\mathsf P(X=r) = rp(1-p)^{r-1}$. The probability of 0 individuals in the next generation = $p$. Let the extinction probability be $K$, then
$$K = p + K\mathsf P(\text{1 individual is generated}) + K^2\mathsf P(\text{2 individuals are generated})+\dots$$
$$=p + p(1-p)K + p(1-p)^2K^2 + \dots$$
$$= p + p(1-p)K/(1-(1-p)K)$$
from sum of infinite GP with $r=\frac K{1-p}$. Solving the RHS we get
$$K = \frac p{1-(1-p)K}$$
$$(1-p)K^2-(1-p)K-pK+p=0$$
$$((1-p)K-p)(K-1)=0$$
Now $K\ne1$ as mean of geometric distribution is $\frac1p>1$, so
$$K=\frac p{1-p}$$

Comment: Honestly I have hard time understanding your question. Where is part (b)? Use LaTeX.

Comment: hi sorry ,b)Suppose that the offspring distribution is geometric with parameter p. Determine the extinction probability

Comment: It's not you but I find that the exercise is not well formed for a math exercise. Who knows the time it takes to reach maturity and the maturity duration vs the pre-maturity delay ? all the children come the same day by g(t) ? finally, what is g(t) ? the growing function for one survivor , for the whole community ? I would prefer a distribution of probabilities ...

Comment: I guess that is the way to solve

Comment: Im on exactly the same problem for hours now and cant solve it yet. Your solution is not the same as in my book (An intermediate course in probabilityour, Allan Gut, Second edition). There its says that $g_{(X_1)}(t)=1-a+a\cdot g (t)$ and $g_{(X_2)}(t)=1-a+a \cdot g (1-a+a\cdot g (t))$.